# Comparing few colums of a file with columns of another file

Tags: shell, sed, awk, diff, uniq

I have two data files 1.txt and 2.txt

1.txt contains valid lines.

For example.

```
1 2 1 2 
1 3 1 3
```

In 2.txt i have an extra coloum, but if you ignore that, I have a few valid lines, and few invalid lines. There could be multiple occurrences of the same line in 2.txt

For example:

```
1 2 1 2 1.9
1 3 1 3 3.4
1 3 1 3 3.4
2 3 2 3 5.6
2 3 2 3 5.6
```

The second and third lines are the same and valid.

The fourth and fifth lines are also the same but invalid.

I want to write a shell script which compares these two files and outputs two files, valid.txt and invalid.txt which look like these...

valid.txt :

```
1 2 1 2 1
1 3 1 3 2
```

and invalid.txt :

```
2 3 2 3 2
```

The last extra column of valid.txt and invalid.txt contains the number of times the line has been repeated in 2.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this awk script works for the example data:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{sub(/ *$/,"");a[$0]++;next}
        {sub(/ [^ ]*$/,"")
         if($0 in a)
                 v[$0]++
         else 
                 n[$0]++
        }
        END{
            for(x in v)print x,v[x] > "valid.txt"
            for(x in n) print x,n[x] >"inv.txt"
        }' file1 file2
```

output:

```
kent$  head inv.txt valid.txt
==> inv.txt <==
2 3 2 3 2

==> valid.txt <==
1 3 1 3 2
1 2 1 2 1
```

Comment: my output using the above script is as follows... `code`          valid.txt ==>
1 3 1 3 2

inv.txt ==>
2 3 2 3 2
1 2 1 2 1

Comment: @gforce89 It could be the trailing spaces problem, I edited the answer, try it again.

Comment: Can you modify this so as to accomadate more than one space between coloums.... As such my data file contains coloums with varying spaces

Comment: never mind, i substituted all spaces with a single space in vi. thanks for the help

Comment: It would be easy, just replace continuous spaces into single.  gsub(/ +/, "") may work.  But I cannot do it for u now. I have to drive after posting this comment. :D